# Error in my function (split Sentence)

Tags: c++

I have problem in my split Sentence function .
The idea of ​​my function split any Sentence and add it to array like

**Example:**

> Sentence:: Hello world.
>     My function will works:: (array[0]= hello, array[1]= world).

**This is my code**

```
void splitSentence(char *Sentence, char symb){
    const int Size = strlen(Sentence);
    string SentenceResult[2];
    int count= 0;
    stringstream stream;
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++){
        stream << Sentence[i];
        if((Sentence[i] == symb) || (Sentence[i] == '\0')){
            SentenceResult[count] = stream.str();
            count++;
            stream.str(" ");
        }
    }
    cout << "Stream: " << stream.str() << endl;
    cout << "Word [0]: " << SentenceResult[0] << endl;
    cout << "Word [1]: " << SentenceResult[1] << endl;
}
```

**The result**

> Stream: world
>   array [0]: hello
>   array [1]:          // empty (must be "world")

What the problem in my function.
Why array[1] is empty .

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the function in a debugger? Then you will see quite clearly what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const int Size = strlen(Sentence);
```

This calculates the length of the string data, but *not* the final null terminator, so your loop will not find the terminator, and won't include the last word. You want to add one to this value to get the full length of the terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop does not run far enough to get to the `Sentence[i] == '\0'` case. It will only run up to the "d" of "hello world", so the conent of the stream is not written anymore into the output array.

You could for example write:

```
const int Size = strlen(Sentence)+1;
```

and you have included the final null byte.

Comment: Eh, three minutes earlier is not "first"? It's your choice which answer you choose, but you should check your definition of "first".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't understand your answer first , but after edit your answer become your answer a understandable answer , but before you edit your answer I've read the answer to someone else ...
  ( I was given to you upvote )

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i <= Size; i++)
```